# Creating Search Option using textbox for Gridview in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, gridview, textbox

I have used the search option for gridview in C# and it worked well.Now I am trying to do it in ASP.net but it isn't filtering the data.These are my codes.

```
 protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string qry = "Select *from Products where ProductName like '%" + tbsearch.Text + "%'";

        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = qry;

        DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);

    }
```

I know I am missing something which isn't binding the data and not filtering, can someone help me with the codes? I am using asp.net for the first time.

Here is the source code of SQLDataSource

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductID], [ProductName], [SupplierID], [CategoryID], [UnitPrice] FROM [Products] WHERE ([ProductName] LIKE @ProductName + '%')">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tbsearch" Name="ProductName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: What if `tbsearch.Text` = `'; DROP TABLE Products;--`? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx to protect yourself against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Hey I have tried using Gridview1.Datasource=dv; gridview.databind(); then I removed DataSourceID from the source code but now it doesn't show the gridview when i type something in the textbox for searching, it filters out the data showing what i wanted but i want the gridview to be loaded first